# Sessions with grunt and php

Tags: php, apache, session, gruntjs

I am using [generator-angular-php](https://npmjs.org/package/generator-angular-php) to create a webapp with a php backend.
Gruntjs acts as a proxy to send the php requests to my local webserver (apache). However, it does not remember (or send to apache) my session information. How can I configure grunt to send the session information to apache? When I access the php pages straight from apache, everything works fine.

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['test'])) {
    $_SESSION['test'] = (int) $_SESSION['test'] + 1;
} else {
    $_SESSION['test'] = 1;
}

echo $_SESSION['test'];

?>
```

Simple example: generate a new project and create a file index.php in the api folder with the code above.
When accessing this file through grunt (on 127.0.0.1:9000/api) I always get back the value 1 when I refresh the page. When I access this file through on 127.0.0.1:8000 the value increases as expected when I refresh. Here is part of the gruntfile that might be relevant:

```
// The actual grunt server settings
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: 'localhost',
    livereload: 35729
  },
  proxies: [
    {
      context: '/api',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8000,
      rewrite: {
        '^/api': ''
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the issue is, but it is important to note that there isn't any "session information" to send along to apache. That is to say, there isn't anything that `grunt-connect-proxy` would know about that PHP would need outside of the request headers (and cookies). So, I think the question is: is `grunt-connect-proxy` sending all headers and cookies through to PHP? Can you check your PHP code to see if you are getting the cookies and report back?